# Manually adding edge-cases to a text classification model

Tags: machine-learning, classification, bias, data-augmentation

Suppose I want to get training data for a model that deals with sentiment analysis for text that indicates an affirmative (yes) or negative (no) response, such as

`"Alright"` $\to$ "YES"

`"no sorry I can't"` $\to$ "NO".

And suppose my way of getting training data is by querying from an SQL database. Suppose I expect there to be a few "difficult" examples that would serve as edge cases to the model, such as something like `"Kinda"` but suppose that the sampling rate for responses of this nature is very low, and since my training data is queried, it may be the case that there will be a few or none examples of this nature.

My questions are:

- Should I upsample this kind of edge case so that my model has been exposed to it to handle this response better? Wouldn't this add bias? I suppose upsampling for a specific response would literally be just repeating it over and over again.
- Do I even need worry about the model not being exposed to this and other "confusing" responses in the training data?

Answer (score 1):

The answers to your questions depend on your problem and distribution of your data. First, you should have an idea on how often those edge cases occur (which maybe you already do). If those cases are, let say <1% of the examples, then MAYBE they are not so important to consider. However, if for your specific application missclassifying those (potentially rare) edge cases result in a high cost for your business or are highly impactful for the problem you want to solve, then it could be important to approach the classification task differently. For instance, as you said, upsampling those cases.

Would upsampling add bias? If your data is not very noisy, your model should generalize better in those edge cases when upsampling. Also, consider your model might be better at recognizing those edge cases at the cost of reducing its capabilities on non-edge cases, but this will not always happen.

In any case, especially if edge examples are not very unfrequent and concern you, I believe it could be worth it experimenting on a slightly upsampled train set on those edge cases.

Comment: Why would upsampling edge cases possibly reduce its capabilities on non-edge cases if it sees the same number of non-edge cases during training?